# lateral limits and regular limit with the same variable

Tags: calculus, limits

I came across 3 problems where the only difference between them is the sign of the value to which $x$ is approaching to. Please see below:

$$
1) \lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{x}{x-3}
$$
$$
2) \lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{x}{x-3}
$$
$$
3) \lim_{x\to3}\frac{x}{x-3}
$$

At least in example 3 we can't use limits arithmetic because if $x=3$ the denominator equals $0$. In that case we should somehow simplify the expression which I don't really see how. In the cases 1 and 2 I feel that the sign can help with simpler solution but not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solve $1$ and $2$, and from that, you can deduce the answer to $3$ (i.e., the limit in $3$ exists if and only if the limits in $1$ and $2$ exist and are equal).

For $1$ and $2$, the sign makes it easier, yes. Take a look at $1$, where, since $x\to 3^-$, you know that $x<3$ and therefore that $x-3<0$.

So, you know that $\frac{x}{x-3}$ will be negative, since $x-3$ is negative (and $x>0$ for $x$ close enough to $3$).

Now, to actually calculate the limit, a *hint*:

- If $x$ is very close to $3$, what happens to $x-3$?
- What, then, happens to $\frac{1}{|x-3|}$?
- What about $\frac1{x-3}$ (remember, $x\to 3^-$)?

Comment: sorry the hint didn't help. I just don't see how to simplify the expression, otherwise it's almost $0$ in the denominator. By the way, the problems were unrelated.

Comment: @Yos You don't have to simplify the expression. You have to find the limit. Also, please tell me your answers to the questions in the hint.

Comment: If $x$ is very close to $3$, then $x-3$ is very close to $0$.

Comment: @Yos And then what happens to $\frac{1}{|x-3|}$?

Comment: it's close to $0$ as well but we can't have $0$ in the denominator

Comment: @Yos Really? So you are saying that if $y$ is close to $0$, then $\frac1y$ is also close to $0$? For example, if $y=0.0000000001$, then $\frac1y$ is close to $0$?

Comment: well if $y=0.00001$ then $1/y=99999$

Comment: @Yos Not really. It's $1000000$. But anyway, would you say this is close to $0$?

Comment: well in this case not really

Comment: @Yos So, try to answer the second question again. If $x$ goes to $3$, what happens to $\frac{1}{|x-3|}$?

Comment: it approaches infinity

Comment: @Yos OK, now answer the third question.

Comment: because the left limit $\to-\infty$ and the right limit $\to +\infty$ then we have a limit when $x \to 3$ which is $\infty$. right?

Comment: @Yos Nope. If left limit is $-\infty$, and right limit is $\infty$, then the two limits are *not* equal, therefore...

Comment: so we don't have a limit

Comment: @Yos There you go. Remember, you might still have to answer $(1)$ and $(2)$ strictly (i.e., using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition), but once you know what you want to prove, it shouldn't be too hard. You have to, for $(2)$, show that for every $M\in\mathbb R$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\frac{x}{x-3}>M$ if $3<x<3+\delta$.

Comment: Thanks! Actually we haven't studied infinities in the class in the context of limits but I guess next class we will.